# How to End a VBScript Called from a Batch File and loop through the Batch File

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

Currently I have a batch file that calls a VBScript and executes the script and exits from that script into the command prompt window that I called the batch file from. I am wanting to return to the batch file from the VBScript and loop back into the beginning of the batch file and ask for the information from the user again and then go back into the script and repeat. I would also like to query the user as to whether they would like to quit or repeat after the VBscript has been run.

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off

C:
cd C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Research\jared

Set "File=basic.dat"

Del "%File%" 2>NUL & If exist "%File%" (
Echo [+] File failed to delete: "%File%" >> "Report.txt" 
)

Set /P datafile=Please enter data file to be analyzed:

Set /P filename=Please enter name for canvas file:


mklink basic.dat %datafile%

cscript Root_VBS_Script_1.vbs %filename%
```

And here is my VBScript (Disregard the SendKeys method, I understand how unreliable it is and will modify this later to not use it):

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set args = WScript.Arguments
arg1 = args.Item(0)

Dim filename

filename = ""&arg1&""

WshShell.AppActivate "Command Prompt"
WshShell.SendKeys "root -b"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.AppActivate "ROOT session"
WshShell.SendKeys ".x analysis.C"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.SendKeys ".x double_gaus.C"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.AppActivate "ROOT session"
WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs{(}"""&filename&"""{)}"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.SendKeys ".q"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"

WScript.Quit
```

I have tried various ways of using the IF ERRORLEVEL command and keeping in mind that it must be in descending order when checked, but nothing is working.

Comment: why dont' you do everything with vbscript.? its cleaner. to call external command (mklink) from vbscript, you can use Run or Exec.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
C:
cd C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Research\jared
Set "File=basic.dat"
:loop
Del "%File%" 2>NUL & If exist "%File%" (
Echo [+] File failed to delete: "%File%" >> "Report.txt" 
)
set "datafile="
Set /P datafile=Please enter data file to be analyzed:
if not defined datafile echo all done - exiting&goto :eof
set "filename="
Set /P filename=Please enter name for canvas file:
if not defined filename echo all done - exiting&goto :eof

mklink basic.dat %datafile%
cscript Root_VBS_Script_1.vbs %filename%
goto loop
```

This should get you going.

Can't see what errorlevels have to do with anything. You appear not to be setting the `vbscript` exit code (need `WScript.Quit yourerrorlevel` else it will exit with `errorlevel` 0, I am told)

If you clear the values before they are input, then you can take advantage of the `set /p` behaviour that the value will remain unchanged if you simply reply with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can also use this characteristic to establish a default value, if that suits.

OR you could define a specific exit codeword like `quit` or `exit`. Using this method, you'd code a line

```
if /i "%var%"=="exit" echo Bye-bye&goto :eof
```

where the quotes protect against an empty or space-containing entry by the user into `var`, the `&` is an inline statement-separator and `:eof` is a special label predefined and understood by `cmd` to mean `end of file` (the colon is required)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but with this code, the batch file still runs into an infinite loop unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This has a loop and a method to exit from the loop.

```
@echo off
:loop    
C:
cd C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Research\jared

Set "File=basic.dat"

Del "%File%" 2>NUL & If exist "%File%" (
Echo [+] File failed to delete: "%File%" >> "Report.txt" 
)
"set datafaile="
Set /P datafile=Please enter data file to be analyzed or press Enter to Quit:
if not defined datafile goto :EOF
Set /P filename=Please enter name for canvas file:


mklink basic.dat %datafile%

cscript Root_VBS_Script_1.vbs %filename%
goto :loop
```

Answer (score 0):

As @brianadams suggested, there's no need for a batch script here. You can do the entire prompting and looping in VBScript and shell out for external commands like `mklink`.

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

sh.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\Jared\Documents\Research\jared"

basicfile = "basic.dat"

Do
  If fso.FileExists(basicfile) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    fso.DeleteFile basicfile, True
    If Err Then fso.OpenTextFile("Report.txt", 8, True).WriteLine _
      "[+] File failed to delete: " & qq(basicfile)
    On Error Goto 0
  End If

  datafile = InputBox("Please enter data file to be analyzed:")
  filename = InputBox("Please enter name for canvas file:")

  sh.Run "cmd /c mklink " & qq(basicfile) & " " & qq(datafile)

  sh.AppActivate "Command Prompt"
  sh.SendKeys "root -b"
  '...
Loop
```